# Change TopAppBar background color from themes.xml

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-appbar

In Jetpack Compose, **TopAppBar** shows `default background color`  irrespective of what we added to `themes.xml`.

So how can we change **`TopAppBar`** background color from **`themes.xml`** so it's applied globally to the App?

```
TopAppBar(
    title = { Text("Activity") },
    navigationIcon = {
        IconButton(onClick = { onBackPressed() }) {
            Icon(Icons.Filled.ArrowBack, contentDescription = null)
        }
    }
)
```

themes.xml

```
<style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

[image]

Note : we can change it through `backgroundColor` attribute of `TopAppBar` but here I want to achieve it globally.

Comment: Check [this](https://google.github.io/accompanist/appcompat-theme/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `TopAppBar` and the other composables the basis of theming   is the [**`MaterialTheme`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#MaterialTheme(androidx.compose.material.Colors,androidx.compose.material.Typography,androidx.compose.material.Shapes,kotlin.Function0)) composable and **not** the AppCompat/MaterialComponents XML themes.

The `TopAppBar` uses the **`backgroundColor`** attribute.
The default value is defined by **`MaterialTheme.colors.primarySurface`**.

You can change these colors globally defining [your theme](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/themes#color) adding your `Colors` and passing them to a `MaterialTheme`:

```
private val LightColors = lightColors(
    primary = Yellow500,
    //...
)
```

Otherwise you can simply use :

```
TopAppBar(
    title = { Text("Activity") },
    backgroundColor = /*...*/,
    /* ... */
)
```

If you want to use the AppCompat XML themes in Jetpack Compose you can use the ***AppCompat Compose Theme Adapter*** provided by the [accompanist](https://google.github.io/accompanist/appcompat-theme/) library.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer explains what to do adequately. There is one thing you might need to keep in mind, though.

`TopAppBar` uses `MaterialTheme.colors.primarySurface` as the background color, and it's defined as the following.

```
[androidx/compose/material/Colors.kt]
val Colors.primarySurface: Color get() = if (isLight) primary else surface
```

In other words, if the device is in the light mode, it uses `primary`, and in the dark mode, it uses `surface`.

Suppose I have a theme with everything as default values.

```
private val DarkColorPalette = darkColors()
private val LightColorPalette = lightColors()

@Composable
fun ComposeTheme(darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(), content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkColorPalette
    } else {
        LightColorPalette
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colors = colors,
        typography = Typography,
        shapes = Shapes,
        content = content
    )
)
```

`lightColors` and `darkColors` have the following values by default.

```
fun lightColors(
    primary: Color = Color(0xFF6200EE),
    ...
)

fun darkColors(
    surface: Color = Color(0xFF121212),
    ...
)
```

When the device is in the light mode, `primary` (`0xFF6200EE`) will be `TopAppBar`'s background color.

[image]

But when the device is in the dark mode, `surface` (`0xFF121212`) is not `TopAppBar`'s background color. It's slightly lighter; `0xFF282828` to be exact.

[image]

The reason is `TopAppBar` has a built-in elevation, which is `4.dp` by default.

```
[androidx/compose/material/AppBar.kt]
@Composable
fun TopAppBar(
    ...
    elevation: Dp = AppBarDefaults.TopAppBarElevation    // 4.dp
) {
```

This most likely won't cause a problem, but it might matter if you want to apply the exactly same background color to somewhere else, such as setting the same color for the status area's background.

```
val systemUiController = rememberSystemUiController()
systemUiController.setSystemBarsColor(color = Color(0xFF282828))
```

[image]

Note that for this particular case, it would be easier if you just go full screen and add padding at the top.

```
WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)

setContent {
    MyAppTheme {
        Surface(
            modifier = Modifier.systemBarsPadding().fillMaxSize(),    // <--
        ) {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i set the dark color of my choice using dark color pallete than?

Comment: In the dark mode, TopAppBar's background is set to Colors.surface, which is Color(0xFF121212) by default. So, you'd define "darkColors(surface = your_color)" and use it in your theme. Just note that it would turn out to be slightly lighter than what you specify, because TopAppBar contains a built-in elevation.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new project in studio, you get a file named Theme.kt, in which there are color palettes named lightColors and darkColors. You should modify the parameters of those values to achieve the result globally in your app.